# Breakline in Raiseerror

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there anyway to breakline and continue on next line in RaiseError? 
`<br/>` and `/n` aren't working

Below is my code:

```
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 16/0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    WHILE(@Count != 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @MaterialName = (SELECT Material FROM #T WHERE Quantity = 0 AND ID = @Count)
        SET @MSG = 'Material %s was not offered.' 
        RAISERROR(@MSG,16,1,@MaterialName);
        SET @Count = @Count - 1
    END
END CATCH
END
```

I dont want to make changes in the data access layer, we only support web, not window app. I want each loop msg to be printed on next line using sql only. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean add a new line into the variable `@MSG`? Use `CHAR(10)` (Line Feed) or `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` (Carriage Return  + Line Feed ).

Comment: I already tried appending CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) at the end. Didnt work sadly.

Comment: SET @MSG = 'Material %s was not offered.' +CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)   This is what I tried. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: What do you mean "Didn't work"? Where are you outputting your result set to, and how are you displaying it?

Comment: If you display output to Text, then possibly you will see a second line. If you display output to grid, or table, you will not realize the carriage return / line feed

Comment: @Eralper the output is in table format not text

Comment: @Larnu I have added +CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) in my stored procedure, not in my frontend

Comment: But what is your frontend..? You say "web" in your post, but that doesn't tell us much. Is it a table, body text, a dialogue box...

Comment: @Larnu ASP.NET MVC

Comment: On SSMS, if you press Ctrl+T it will display outputs as Text results.

Comment: If you're using a web front end, then the correct syntax for a linebreak is `<br />`. Like you stated in your post. Thus `SET @MSG = 'Material %s was not offered.<br />'`. If this isn't working either, then I'd suggest the problem is in your front end, not SQL.

Comment: On Windows, newline is Carriage Return **then** Line Feed, so `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`, not `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)`

Answer (score 1):

if you include the line break in the text it will work.

```
SET @MSG = 'Material %s was not offered.
'
```

Note that the end quote is on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @newline varchar
select @newline=char(10) + char(13)
raiserror ('Newline test %sThis line is on a new line',0,0,@newline)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

I'm no pro in sql but I think this will help

```
Char(10)
```

Inserts a new line break a good guide about it is here: https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/sql-server/sql-how-to-insert-new-lineline-break-in-string/

I've also seen `\n` used before but I don't know if that can be used in your circumstance